# Best practice to implement: supervisor can search records of his subordinates?

Tags: c#, java, database, security, access-control

By implement a method in DAO layer(or Data Access Layer) like this:
getRecordsBySupervisor(String staffid)?
What is the best practice to control this kinds of access ?  It seems that most of the security frameworks are used to control the access of a specific address upon a role, but not work in this case?

So what is the best practice to have a decent implement methods for this case, and better for reuse in future ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is security over records. When an employee creates a record, you have to grant right over it to the employee´s supervisor. Then, your getRecordsBySupervisor just has to return all the records which can be seem by the supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant and transparent approach to this would be to use dynamic data filters.

Take a look at hibernate filters:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html

http://mattfleming.com/node/243